# How to do something if cancel button on save file dialog was clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

I am using c# WinForms. I have a save dialog box that pops up and a message box after that that says it was saved successfully.

I just realized that if a user clicks cancel, my message box still comes.

How do i tell when a user clicks the cancel button on a save dialog box and then do something when it is cancelled?

Comment: Add the code to your question showing how you display the Save Dialog Box and when it displays the message box.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A save dialog box after closing has the DialogResult property set to what happens.
In your case:

```
if (mySaveDialog.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) { /* show saved ok */ }
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can also use DialogResult.Cancel

Comment: Can confirm this is the best way - also me

Comment: It wouldn't let me do mySaveDialog.DialogResult but Habib's answer below worked great! (same thing really just a typo i think) Thank yo so much!

Comment: @jordan.peoples, There is nothing wrong with my answer and also it was posted first (almost 30 seconds earlier). I am fine with the accept, just wanted to clarify

Answer (score 17):

Use [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    //user cancelled out
}
```

For [`SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show("your Message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using WPF in a open file dialog, the better option I found is to store the selected file path (`File.ReadAllText(filedialog.Filename)` ) in a `string` and then check if its `!== null` wich means the user has a file selected. If the file path is `null` so the file is empty or the user just clicked on cancel button