# How do I "do something" when a SaveFileDialog is cancelled?

Tags: c#, winforms

**NB:** The answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693300/how-to-do-something-if-cancel-button-on-save-file-dialog-was-clicked) is out of date.

---

So, I have a save dialog box:

```
...
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.ShowDialog();

// SaveFileDialog.[Whatever] - Init code basically.

if (sfd.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Definitely do something.
        Console.Print("File selected.");
    }
if (sfd.DialogResult == DialogResult.Abort)
    {
        // Maybe the opposite of the above?
        Console.Print("File selection Cancelled");
    }
if ( ... ) { }
    and so on.
```

But... `SaveFileDialog.DialogResult` has been replaced by events instead...

And that the only available events are `SaveFileDialog.FileOK`, `SaveFileDialog.Disposed` and `SaveFileDialog.HelpRequest`.

How do I trigger an event (or move to a line of code) based when the user clicked **Cancel** rather than completing it (Clicking **Save**)?

I'm looking to branch based on whether the user cancels or successfully selects the file location to save to.

Comment: You can check the result of `yourSaveFileDialog.ShowDialog()`

Comment: It is incorrect to say the DialogResult has been replaced, the MSDN code example shows this is still working. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working with `DialogResult` is not deprecated and also those events are not something new.
To perform an action for Cancel, you can create your `SaveFileDialog` and configure it, you can call `ShowDialog` and then check the result:

```
var sfd= new SaveFileDialog();
//Other initializations ...
//sfd.Filter= "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
//sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";

if(sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Save Clicked");
    //ِDo something for save
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cancel Clicked");
    //Do something for cancel
}
```

You can access to selected file using [`FileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property, for example `MessageBox.Show(sfd.FileName);`

Comment: "SaveFileDialog.DialogResult has been replaced by events instead..", it appeared that the OP does not wish to use DialogResult?

Comment: @David: there's no good reason to do that over this method. Sure, if the OP wants to do it the hard way, they are free to build machinery to deal with that. I don't see why we should pander to that.

Comment: I agree, see my comments for the OP.

Comment: Good answer solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818152/savefiledialog-is-throwing-indexoutofrangeexception-when-canceled